# Simplifying a query (with left outer join)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization, outer-join

Our app has been using this query for a while now:

```
SELECT id 
FROM invoice 
WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT invoice_id FROM invoice_transaction) 

#437 rows returned
```

In a code review, this query was rewritten with a left outer join:

```
SELECT invoice.id 
FROM invoice 
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice_transaction on invoice.id=invoice_transaction.invoice_id 

#586 rows returned
```

The first query returns 437 rows and the second (supposedly identical) query returns 586 rows.  Is this not a valid use of the left outer join?

What would be a better way to rewrite this query?

Thank you!

Comment: They're not at all the same.  Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html): you can make the second equivalent to the first with the filter `WHERE invoice_transaction.invoice_id IS NULL`.

Comment: The venn diagrams at this location seemed to indicate that the left outer join was what I'm looking for. http://www.khankennels.com/blog/index.php/archives/2007/04/20/getting-joins/

Comment: Now that I think about it, this seems obvious.  Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following query should return the same results of the first query:

```
SELECT invoice.id 
FROM invoice 
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice_transaction 
             on invoice.id = invoice_transaction.invoice_id
WHERE invoice_transaction.invoice_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

best way is this

```
SELECT id 
FROM invoice as i
WHERE not exists
(SELECT invoice_id FROM invoice_transaction as it where it.invoice_id=i.id )
```